# How to replace the closest <tr> based on index

Tags: c#, html, string, replace

I am manipulating an HTML File with C#.
I load the HTML in a string and do multiple manipulations (removing, adding, and replacing part of it).

One of the replacements I need to do is the following:

I have a table with multiple rows and cells. Example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <font style="background-color: SkyBlue" color="blue">my text</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="img.png"></img>
            <font style="background-color: red" color="white">my second text</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

1. Search for any occurence of `style="background-color: red"`
2. Remove it from where it is, and add it to the parent row (`<tr>`)

So in our example, the html would become:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <font style="background-color: SkyBlue" color="blue">my text</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: red" >
        <td>
            <img src="img.png"></img>
            <font color="white">my second text</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Notice how the entire row is now background red, instead of the  tag

**What I've done so far**

- I created an extension method to find all the indexes of `style="background-color: red"` and returns a `List<int> indexes`
- I replaced all occurrences of `style="background-color: red"` with empty strings

**Problem**

Now I'm stuck on replacing the corresponding `<tr>` parent with `<tr style="background-color: red" >`

How can I achieve that? if there a way to get the closest `<tr>` element based on an index, and replace it with what I want?
Thanks

Comment: If you are going to manipulate DOM then manipulate it as DOM, not as a string.

Comment: HTMLAgilityPack would help your cause big time.

Answer (score 1):

You just need handle html string as XML to find the parent

Sample:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(stream);

foreach (var coordinate in xmlDoc.Descendants("font"))
{
    if (coordinate.Attribute("style").Value.IndexOf("background-color: red", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
    {
        coordinate.Attribute("style").Remove();
        coordinate.Parent.Parent.Add(new XAttribute("style", "background-color: red"));
    }
};

return xmlDoc.ToString();
```